# Basic Question for new Java Student

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and I have no other programming experience. I am  struggling with a homework question and I have only gotten so far. I am very sure this question is very simple to this community but I would like to request lemans terms help regarding it.

Question:
Write a method called reverse, that takes an int as argument and returns an int. The method reverses the digits of the given number and returns it. If given 5433, the method returns 3345.

Call the method in a main with an arbitrary value and print the result to the screen.

(This is my code snippit so far: ( how do I do the reverse that is spoke of? its probably very simple but apparently I need help with it) Thanks in advance!)

```
// Exercise 2.8.3
public class BlackBelt8 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

  reverse(5433);

 }
 public static int reverse(int x){
  System.out.println(x);
  return x;

 }

}
```

---

**Update:** I worked through all of the suggested solutions. Thank you

Comment: It seems to me you need to analyse the problem a little more. How do you turn that number around?

Comment: The question asks for main to print out the result, not the reverse method.

Comment: Try changing it to a string, reversing the characters, and changing it to a number again.

Comment: somebody with enough reputation please change leman to layman and snippit tp snippet.

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to do this. I won't give you the code, but hopefully I'll put you in the correct direction.

1. You can turn the integer into a string and reverse the string. Then turn it back into an integer. If you want to do this, I suggest looking at Integer.parseInt and String.valueOf.
2. This is probably the better way. Integers in programming languages will return only the quotient of the answer. So when you do 5 / 2, it returns 2. The [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) returns the remainder of the division. So 5 % 2 (% is the modulo operator) would be equal to 1.

Observe that you can use the division and modulo of 10 to reverse the integer.

And as mentioned in one of the comments, you'll want to only return the result from your function. Remove the System.out.println from the reverse function and put it in main. So you would call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverse(123));
}
```

EDIT: This is in response to the comments.

In Java, there are two types of data. Native types and objects. The native types are int, double, float, long, byte, and char. These are the only types that are not objects and toString doesn't exist for them. Each one of them has an Object that you can use instead though. For example, int's object counterpart is Integer.

Everything else is an object and is derived from the base class [Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and is related to [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). The toString method is used to give a human-readable string representation of whatever object it is called on.

Any class can have their own implementation of the toString method which will return (ideally) a human-readable string.

Comment: like the way you presented the answer

Comment: Would you advise me to look into the toString() method as well? I found that while researching the Int.parseInt java methods. I appreciate you not giving me the solution, it helps me learn to research instead of regurgitate information.

Comment: It's helpful to know what toString is, but it won't help for this problem. I'll edit my answer with a little explanation anyway though.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse of 123 is 321
Observe that
123 = 100*1 + 10*2 + 1*3
and
321 = 1*1 + 10*2 + 100*3

How do you split 123 in 1,2,3?  How do you iterate through all the digits?
Are you familiar with loop constructs?
Do you know what division remainder is?

Comment: He is supposed to use recursion instead of loops.

Comment: @Enabren why?? what makes you think so?

Comment: I have started loop constructs but I was trying to stay within the instructions. I am sure an array and enhanced for loop may be an easier and more efficient way to answer the question but I was just checking to see if I was missing something. And of course I learn from the comments!

Comment: I must be on crack. I must have read "reverse" as "recurse" and got it stuck in my head.

Comment: you don't need an array, really.  you can accumulate as you go.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ive only been doing java for 2 weeks now. My brain might explode but Im loving it

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```
public class BlackBelt8 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println(reverse(5433));

 }
 public static int reverse(int x){
  String aString = String.valueOf(x);

  StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder(aString);
  StringBuilder strReverseBuild = strBuild.reverse();

  int resultInt = Integer.parseInt(strReverseBuild.toString());
  return resultInt;

 }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

x = Integer.parseInt(x.toString().Reverse());

Comment: Native types don't have a toString function (you would have to use String.valueOf) and Java String class doesn't have a reverse method. You have a combination of a C# answer and a Java answer, but will compile nowhere. You should also not just post an answer without an explanation on a homework question...

Comment: I am just working through the Blackbeltfactory.com course materials but you are right. I will provide more explanation than I did  before posting an answer next time. I am new to the forums as well.